# Search Medicine name in pharma industry with few characters from each word in a lengthy medicine name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Product name:

1. AMOXICILLIN SUSP 250MG/5ML 100ML
2. AMOXIN SUSP 500MG/5ML 100ML

Client requirement is when they search the product like

- "amoxi" or "amo susp" or "amox susp" or "amo sus 250 100"
- 100 250 sus amo or amox susp**

Result when I send parameter `amox susp` to the stored procedure will be the above two products as both contain this data.

We need to display all similar product names like "amoxilin 10mg" or "amoxilin 30mg". Basically if the product name is too lengthy he is going to search the word using few characters from the different words in same product. Sometimes even reverse too should work like mentioned in point b. Looking for inputs to achieve this.

Without using full-text search and index would like to achieve this.

Comment: All pieces of text are mandatory?

Comment: @FDavidov - didnt get you

Comment: You would be far better off passing those values as a table variable, not as a (space?) delimited list. Especially when SQL Server 2008 (which is completely unsupported) has no in built way splitting the values.

Comment: @TheImpaler - as i mentioned without using full text search

Comment: Why don't you want to use full text search, which was designed for these types of queries?  Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: What I mean is that you may be searching for, say, **aaa bbb ccc** while there are entries matching only **aaa bbb** and **bbb ccc**. So, rephrasing, do you need that all the **SEEDS** you include into you search strings **MUST** appear in the result? Incidentally, what you are looking for is using Regular Expressions, but SQL Server does not support it.

Comment: @FDavidov - got it..will be needing aaa with which the medicine name starts

Comment: @FDavidov - the medicine name starts with amox(amox 100 250) or amox(amox tab 100ml) or amox(amox sub 2kg), i.e the first word its going to search which is mandatory i mean the first word is the starting point for medicine

Comment: @PrathapGangireddy, my question still remains unanswered. I got that **AMOX** is mandatory, but what about the other pieces? Are they also mandatory? My point here is that if, besides the first piece, any or all other elements are optional, you will need to device a mechanism that **_rates_** each found entry such that, if you only want to get a single result, it is selected correctly, else (more than one result), you want to list them in some predefined order (e.g. best match first/last). Try any search in Google and you will see what I mean (except for sponsored entries appearing first).

Comment: It seems like you copy pasted your client requirements on to stack overflow without making any effort. In fact going by prior questions, you do this a lot. What did you try? Why can't you use full text search, because that makes the most sense here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and effective way of performing this search without using full text search is to (1) use the logic on the procedure to split the parameter into "words" and then (2) perform the search using `LIKE` and `OR`.

For example, if you have the parameter `100 250 sus amo` you can split it into:

- 100
- 250
- sus
- amo

Then the query is:

```
select *
from t
where lower(description) like lower('%100%')
   or lower(description) like lower('%250%')
   or lower(description) like lower('%sus%')
   or lower(description) like lower('%amo%')
```

Comment: One more point is that the medicine name starts with amox(amox 100 250) or amox(amox tab 100ml) or amox(amox sub 2kg), i.e the first word its going to search which is mandatory i mean the first word is the starting point for medicine